# Derivative involving vec() operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $X$ be a $m\times n$ matrix, $B$ be a $n\times n$ matrix and $D$ be a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with diagonal elements $d_i$. Is it possible to write down the derivative of the following expression wrt the vector $d$ (or matrix $D$)?

$$ \text{vec}(X(B+D)^{-1})^T \text{vec}(X(B+D)^{-1}) $$

Comment: Hmm, what is the "$\operatorname{vec}$" operator?

Comment: The vectorization of a m × n matrix A, denoted vec(A), is the mn × 1 column vector obtained by stacking the columns of the matrix A on top of one another: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a diag() function which returns the main diagonal of its matrix argument as a column vector, and a Diag() function which generates a diagonal matrix from a vector argument.

Then define the following matrices
$$\eqalign{
A &= D = {\rm Diag}(a) \\
C &= A+B &\implies dC=dA={\rm Diag}(da) \\
Y &= XC^{-1} &\implies dY=-XC^{-1}\,dC\,C^{-1}  \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of the new matrices
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {\rm vec}(Y)^T\,{\rm vec}(Y) = Y:Y \\
d\phi &= 2Y:dY \\
  &= -2Y:\left(XC^{-1}\,dC\,C^{-1}\right) \\
  &= -2\left(C^{-T}X^TYC^{-T}\right):dC \\
  &= -2\left(C^{-T}X^TYC^{-T}\right):{\rm Diag}(da) \\
  &= -2\operatorname{diag}\left(C^{-T}X^TYC^{-T}\right):da \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial a}
  &= -2\operatorname{diag}\left(C^{-T}X^TYC^{-T}\right) \\
  &= -2\operatorname{diag}\Big((A+B)^{-T}X^TX(A+B)^{-1}(A+B)^{-T}\Big) \\\\
}$$

---

In some of the steps above, a colon is used to represent the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)
}$$
The cyclic property of the trace allows the terms in such products to be rearranged in a number of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T &= B:A \\
A:BC &= AC^T:B &= B^TA:C \\
}$$
The variable name $D$ was replaced with $A$ because visually, $da$ is easily identified as the differential of the vector $a$, while $dd$ looks ambiguous.

Comment: Clear! The link to the Frobenius norm was the missing piece. I think in the last line $X$ and $(A+B)^{-1}$ need to be switched, right?

Comment: The factors have been switched to the correct order.